# How to scale down images in css

Tags: html, css

Hello how can I resize  my 320 by 320 youtube Icon
[image]

I want it the size of an icon like apps look in the desktop  small however I can't seem to be able to do that with

```
.icons{
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
}
```

or

```
<div class="icons">
    <img src="/img/youtube icon.png" width: 30px; height: 30px; alt="">
</div>
```

here's the code

this is the HTML code -- (Ps I have removed the height and width code as it did not work)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/board.css">
    <title>Board</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Board">
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="user">
                <h3>Good Morning, Admin!</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="icons">
                <img src="/img/youtube icon.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-panel">
        <div class="heading">

        </div>
        <div class="dashboard">

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the CSS code --

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@font-face{
    src: url(/fonts/Coiny-Regular.ttf);
    font-family: Coiny;
}

body, html{
    background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.Board{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: left;
}

.panel{
    background-color: white;
    width: 450px;
    height: 650px;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    box-shadow: 7px 7px 7px 7px rgba(202, 202, 202, 0.3);
}

.right-panel{
    background-color: white;
    width: 950px;
    height: 650px;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    box-shadow: 7px 7px 7px 7px rgba(202, 202, 202, 0.3);
}

.user h3{
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    text-align: start;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    font-family: Coiny, cursive;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: your code is wrong with `<div class="icons">
    <img src="/img/youtube icon.png" width: 30px; height: 30px; alt="">
</div>` if you are going to put the css on the img tag it needs to be like this: `width="30px"`

Answer (score 3):

`.icons` targets elements with that class so you can either do

`<img src="/img/youtube icon.png" class="icons" alt="">`

or update your selector to target elements within that class:

```
.icons img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do this, but I think with your example in your question you have improper coding to get the width and height of your image:

For example, this:

```
<div class="icons">
    <img src="/img/youtube icon.png" width: 30px; height: 30px; alt="">
</div>
```

Should look like this:

```
<div class="icons">
    <img src="/img/youtube icon.png" width="30px" height="30px" alt="">
</div>
```

If you were doing inline style, which I wouldn't recommend, you could do something like this:

```
<div class="icons">
    <img src="/img/youtube icon.png" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;" alt="">
</div>
```

**The best way to do this would just to have a simple css like this:**

`.icons img { width:30px; height: 30px; }`

Comment: If you use width and height attributes, they need to be integer values with no units

Answer (score 1):

Move your class on `img` instead on `div`:

```
    <div>
        <img class="icons" src="/img/youtube icon.png" alt="">
    </div>
```